# Dynamic Image Files in KV - The Simplest Approach?

Tags: python, image, dynamic, kivy, kivy-language

I want to include a dynamic image file in my Kivy App. I managed to pass the string of the filename from my .py file to my .kv file, but for some reason I cannot open the image using this variable (only through hardcording it).

I've googled around and only found overly complicated approaches to this. I've tried to copy paste them all and somehow fit them in, but none really worked. Now I'm wondering if any of you knows a simpler solution to my problem.

Here's a snippet of my .py file where I use an ID to dynamically generate my file name

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, StringProperty
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from database import DataBase


class DetailedResults(Screen):

    def on_enter(self, *args):
        filename = "itemdiffplot" + str(self.key_id) + ".png"
        self.filename.text = filename

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

kv = Builder.load_file("my.kv")

sm = WindowManager()
db = DataBase("keys.txt")

screens = [DetailedResults(name="d_results")] # Gotta add all my Windows here always
for screen in screens:
    sm.add_widget(screen)

sm.current = "enter_key"

class MyMainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return sm

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyMainApp().run()
```

the .kv file where I first display the "filename" as a Label and then try to open it as an image:

```
WindowManager:
    DetailedResults:

<DetailedResults>:
    name: "d_results"
    filename: filename
    FloatLayout:
        cols:1

        FloatLayout:
            size: root.width, root.height/2

            Label:
                pos_hint: {"x":0.5, "top":0.7}
                size_hint: 0.4, 0.12
                id: filename
                multiline: False
                font_size: (root.width**2 + root.height**2) / 14**4

            Image:
                source: ("<%s>" % filename)
```

the output:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qLuR7.png

Right now I'm getting the error message that the Image I'm trying to open is not a string, but a Label object ("Error reading file <>").

I'm a huge KV newbie, so I don't understand all of this too well, so I hope you guys can help me.

Comment: Did you declare the property `filename = ObjectProperty()` in your `DetailedResults` class? Also, please paste the full traceback. Also, please post a full minimal runnable example.

Comment: 1. re: ObjectProperty I did do it now, but that didn't change anything. 

2. I'm not getting a real traceback, just this: 
"[ERROR  ] [Image       ] Error reading file <<kivy.uix.label.Label object at 0x0000022C7FB64B40>>
[ERROR  ] [Image       ] Error reading file <<kivy.uix.label.Label object at 0x0000022C08E5DC10>>"
3. I edited my post to hopefully make it runnable. You just have to define a key_id

Comment: Have you tried just adding an `id` (perhaps `image_id`) to your `Image` widget in `kv`? Then in your `on_enter()`, simply do `self.ids.image_id.source = filename`. You don't even need the `filename` property in the `DetailedResults` class.

Comment: Another possibility is to change `source: ("<%s>" % filename)` to `source: filename.text`.

Comment: O wow it actually worked changing it to "source: filename.text". I can't believe I didn't think of that myself haha. Thank you a lot. Interestingly though it only works if I keep the Label. If I delete the Label, I get an error saying "'filename' is not defined"